# Assigning a value to a objects created at run time (python)

Tags: python, list, object, variable-assignment, nested-loops

I am trying to use a while loop to create object to populate a list of a user defined type until a certain condition is met. I want to assign a value to each object based on the number of iterations the loop has completed. For example:

```
class WalkingPeeps:

def___init___(self):
     self.location = 0

def leftAt(self,time):
     self.tleft = time

def changePos(self):
     self.location += random.choice([1, -1])

objectList =[] 
location_reached = False
time = 0

 while not location_reached
      objectList.append(WalkingPeeps())
      for x in objectList:
           x.tleft = time
           if x.location == 20:
                location_reached = True
      time+=1

print("Person left at: ",x.tleft)
print("Person arrived at: ", time)
```

However, when it runs, it just set the time the object was created to one less than when the person reached 20. Any pointers? Hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code is full of syntactic errors, like no space here `def__init__(self)` or missing colon here `def leftAt(self, time)` and here `while not location_reached`. Is it your actual code?

Comment: This is a version of my code. I typed it with a handheld because my pc gives me a connection timed out every time I try to access the site

Comment: @Calum x does exist, there's no loop scoping in Python

Answer (score 1):

In python, loops do not define their own scope. When you write

```
for x in objectList: ...
```

There variable x is created. At each step in the loop, the variable is updated. When the loop ends, the variable is **not** destroyed. Therefore, when you print x.tleft, you're printing the time on the last x, which by definition is 20, since you break the loop only when x.tleft == 20.

Furthermore, since you loop over every single element at each phase and update its time, you're setting each elements time to the most reccent time. Therefore, all elements have time == 20, when you terminate. What you mean, I believe, is to only update the last element

What I think you want to print, to check that your loop is working is,

```
for obj in objectList:
    print( obj.tleft )
```

You would then see the expected behaviour

You also have many errors, including some syntax errors and some that make the code enter an infinite loop. This is the version I worked with, in good faith (try and make sure that the the only bugs in your code are the one's you're asking about!)

```
class WalkingPeeps: pass # None of the methods were relevant

objectList =[]
location_reached = False
time =0

while not location_reached:
    objectList.append(WalkingPeeps())
    x = objectList[-1]
    x.tleft = time
    # you need to check tleft, not location; location is never set
    if x.tleft == 20: 
    location_reached = True
    time+=1


print("Person left at: ",x.tleft)
print("Person arrived at: ", time)
for person in objectList: print(person.tleft)
```

A far more readable and concise version of this code would be:

```
class WalkingPerson:
       def __init__(self,time=0):
              self.time=time

objectList = [WalkingPerson(t) for t in range(20)]
```

Comment: That prints out the time every object was created until one reaches 20. So I'm  sure it's creating multiple objects. My goal is to get the time the object that reaches 20 first was created. I edited some issues. Forgive me I'm using a mobile device.

Comment: You may have fixed some issues, but the code you posted still won't compile... I can't really reproduce your error in earnest if your "minimal example" isn't real Python